# How to use two search dropdown boxes simultaneously in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a database project in MVC ASP.Net. I would like the user to be able to use two dropdown lists and for BOTH sets of results to show on the same screen.

INDEX VIEW:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p class="search">
        Team: @Html.DropDownList("playerTeam", "All")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
    </p>
    <p class="search">
        Team: @Html.DropDownList("playerTeam2", "All")
    </p>
}
```

HOME CONTROLLER:

```
private PlayersDBEntities4 _db = new PlayersDBEntities4();
public ActionResult Index(string playerTeam, string playerTeam2)
    {
        var TeamList = new List<string>();
        var TeamQuery = from t in _db.PlayerInfoes
                        orderby t.Team
                        select t.Team.ToUpper();

        TeamList.AddRange(TeamQuery.Distinct());
        ViewBag.playerTeam = new SelectList(TeamList);

        var TeamList2 = new List<string>();
        var TeamQuery2 = from t in _db.PlayerInfoes
                        orderby t.Team
                        select t.Team.ToUpper();

        TeamList2.AddRange(TeamQuery2.Distinct());
        ViewBag.playerTeam2 = new SelectList(TeamList2);

var players = from p in _db.PlayerInfoes select p; //this is my database

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(playerTeam))
        {
            players = players.Where(x => x.Team == playerTeam);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(playerTeam2))
        {
            players = players.Where(x => x.Team == playerTeam2);
        }

return View(players.ToList());
    }
```

So for example if I selected a team in the first dropdown box, and another team in the second dropdown box, the search results would show players of BOTH teams (at the moment each box works individually to show one team, but when used together I get no search results).

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: Your question does not make a whole lot of sense, I think you should edit to clarify.

Comment: How about using an `or`? `players = players.Where(x => x.Team == playerTeam || x.Team == playerTeam2);`

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(playerTeam))
    {
        players = players.Where(x => x.Team == playerTeam);
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(playerTeam2))
    {
        players = players.Where(x => x.Team == playerTeam2);
    }
```

Go for something like

```
players = players.Where(x.Team == playerTeam || x.Team == playerTeam2)
```

And be sure that none of them  will ever be null, an empty string will not change the search result unless you have teams without names.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searching)
{

 var items = new SelectList(new[] { "CSE", "ECE","EEE","IT","MBA" });
 ViewBag.DEP = items;
  ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(db.Sridevis, "Department", "DEP");

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searching))
        {
            faculty = faculty.Where( x.Department.StartsWith(search) );
        }
        return View(faculty.ToList());
```

}

```
HTML!
 <div>Department</div>
                                                            <div>
                                                                @Html.DropDownList("searching", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DEP, "Select Department", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                            </div>
```